# Is mysql update on join table consistent?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables t1 and t2 with primary key `id` and integer `amount` each.
I need to "move" amounts from t2 to t1, but not lost any amounts and not get extra. Is it possible by single update with autocommit and without transaction isolations?

I mean something like this:

```sql
update t1 join t2 using (id)
    set t1.amount = t1.amount + t2.amount, t2.amount = 0;
```

Is it guaranteed that total amount will not be changed by this statement? Or it's possible (if change `t2.amount` during this execution or interrupt it) that `t1.amount` increase by not the same value that `t2.amount` decrease?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html

Comment: What's the problem with transactions? This is what those were designed for.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That link is for single table update. I've read somewhere that the evaluation order of columns in SET clause is "undetermined" for multi-table updates - But can't find the source.

Comment: [here it is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html): "Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order. "

Comment: @Shadow I'm afraid about exception in code within transaction that cause continue using the same dbi connection by another code of the process without commit or rollback the interrupted transaction. So I create a new dbi connection for each transaction, and it's slower than autocommit statements with existing connection. I know it's not the best solution but it's out of scope here.

Comment: @PavelG then it would be better if you learnt how to handle exceptions in your application code, rather than trying to do hacks in the database layer.

Answer (score 1):

Though it seems to work as expected, it's documented as "unreliable":

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to
>   right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that
>   assignments are carried out in any particular order.

([MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) )

But you can calculate the sum in a derived table:

```
update t1
join t2 using (id)
join (
  select id, t1.amount + t2.amount as amount
  from t1 join t2 using(id)
) x using (id)
set t1.amount = x.amount,
    t2.amount = 0
```

In this case the order in the SET clause doesn't matter since the assignments don't interfere.

For InnoDB a single UPDATE statement is atomic. It's either executed completly or not at all. If something goes wrong during the execution (eg. server crash or data type overflow) all changes will be rolled back or just not commited.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I created a test with these tables, 1000 records in each and 2 simultaneous processes, one increasing amounts in t2 and second move amounts from t2 to t1 in loop, 1000 iterations each.
I got correct result with "simple" update (but it's not guaranteed by mysql) and error `Deadlock found when trying to get lock` with temp table x.
Tested on mariadb 10.1.